# clearing out voltage of a synchronous circuit

Tags: circuit-design

I apologize if this has already been answered, but i can't seem to find this question anywhere, maybe because i'm not using the right terminology in searching.

My understanding is that most processor chips use MOSFET transistors. I imagine that the circuit (chip) is in some sort of neutral state before use, and then a control signal sets off a chain reaction whereby one mosfet activation allows voltage to rise/drop in a circuit, causing activation/deactivation of another mosfet and so on.

At some point, we say (i think) that the circuit is settled, and the output voltages are correct representations of the computation. So we store them in a memory cell and it's time to run the whole process over again.

But now my circuit has a different voltages in the circuit than it's initial configuration!  I would imagine the solution would be draining the voltage, but every solution i think of seems to have some issue or other.

How exactly do we drain the voltage of a reusable circuit to ensure it has the same start conditions every time?

Comment: You use pull-down resistors to drain the MOSFET gate capacitances so that they promptly discharge when you remove power to the circuit. Or connect a pull-down transistor to the gate of every MOSFET and drive these pull-down transistors simultaneously so it acts like a reset signal.

Comment: This looks like a really promising concept.  I will google around and see what i can learn about them, but if what you're saying is correct this might be exactly what i'm looking for.  Thank You!

Comment: Registers may have a reset, set or clear input.  Data is sync'd by clock edge.

Comment: I should be clearer, don't pull down (or up) EVERY transistor in your circuit since that could cause things like short-circuits if you happen to make every transistor default or reset blindly to the same state. You only really need to do it with key transistors (like circuits with memory). You pull up or down based on what the "default" value of the transistor should be.

Comment: My dude, i just watched a video on this technique and it looks like it might be what i'm looking for.  You confused me with this statement though, 'You only really need to do it with key transistors'.  Why would that be?  I'm concerned with resetting a complex circuit for each clock cycles, like resetting a cpu circuit (not counting the registers) to be run for another clock cycle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How exactly do we drain the voltage of a reusable circuit to ensure it has the same start conditions every time?

Logic circuits are arranged so that the output is forced to a given value based on the inputs.  You don't need to "drain" the voltage out of the answer -- that happens automatically, if necessary.

Comment: I'm not concerned with draining voltage out of the answer, but if voltage is getting locked up in the circuit, it will need to be drained before the next clock cycle?

Comment: Voltage is not a substance, to get locked up into anything.  And the answer to "well, what is voltage, then?" will take approximately one chapter (maybe two) in a basic college physics text.  It'll start with an explanation of electric charges, then move on to electric fields, and then finally explain electrical potential (AKA voltage).

Comment: I understand that voltage is not a substance.  In terms of a MOSFTETS, the gate allows current flow when the charge density(i.e. voltage) at gate hits some threshold high or low value.  Presumable, this gate is itself attached to another MOSFET.  At this point in time, there is voltage/charge stored in the wire connected at the first MOSFET's Gate.

Before the next clock cycle, the circuit's should all have their electron density(voltage) returned to around their starting values, shouldn't they?

Comment: "Before the next clock cycle, the circuit's should all have their electron density(voltage) returned to around their starting values..."  Nope.  There's no need for that.  Transistors aren't mechanical things with pawls and ratchets; they don't stick in a state (at least not by themselves).  Change the input to a gate in the right way, and the output changes.  They're asynchronous devices in that regard.

Comment: 'they don't stick in a state (at least not by themselves)'.  I think this is where we have a disconnect in understanding.  As i understand a MOSFET transistors state is based on the voltage at the gate.  If i have 2 MOSFETS, where the first has its drain attached to the seconds Gate, on each clock cycle i will need to drain the wire connecting that drain and gate

Comment: Again, nope.  But at least we've advanced from really simple physics to really simple circuit theory.  Go out on the web, find a schematic for a CMOS gate, and study it.  You'll find that, first, your "first transistor" is actually a pair, and second, that that pair of transistors **actively drives** the gate(s) of following transistors.  The "voltage draining" is **happening all the time**, there's no need to do it as a separate step.

Comment: You know what, i think this is actually what i was looking for.  I need to research a bit more to be sure, but looks like I'll probably be marking this as the correct answer.  Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

> At some point, we say (i think) that the circuit is settled, and the
>   output voltages are correct representations of the computation. So we
>   store them in a memory cell and it's time to run the whole process
>   over again.

This is what clocks are for, the circuits are designed so the logic settles before the next round of clock cycles.

> How exactly do we drain the voltage of a reusable circuit to ensure it
>   has the same start conditions every time?

This is what resets are for, every computer has a reset line. This resets the digital logic to a *known state* before computation. Without resets, digital logic can be metastable (in between 1 and 0), resets force memory elements in logic to go to a known state (either 1 or 0) which is determined by the hardware design. If your circuit does not have resets, perhaps you should consider resets in your design. Resets come in two "flavors" [asynchronous and synchronous](https://www.embedded.com/design/debug-and-optimization/4458668/Asynchronous-reset-synchronization-and-distribution-----challenges-and-solutions)

Comment: This terminology 'reset line' looks promising.  Most of the articles i'm seeing, including the one you linked, seem to be focused on 'power up'.  For example, the first line of the article you posted is

"Lack of coordination between asynchronous resets and synchronous logic clocks leads to intermittent failures on power up".

However skimming the rest of the article it seems to also mention the relationship between resets and clock cycles, so i will check that out in a bit as it seems to be related to what i want to know.  Thank You!

Comment: Another user mentioned 'pull-up/down' resistor, but i don't see this in the article you posted anywhere.  I'm wondering if these are separate concepts.